# Бот Discord отвечает 2 раза. Disnake Python

Tags: python, discord, disnake

При написании команды 2 раза, даже на разных серверах, пока кнопки не исчезнут, при нажатии на одну из кнопок "Удалить предупреждение" бот отвечает 2 раза вместо одного, но при этом удаляется только одно предупреждение.
Иногда возникает такая ошибка: Command raised an exception: HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 40060): Interaction has already been acknowledged.

row- количество предупреждений, полученных пользователем

i - максимальное количество предупреждений

Как это исправить?

```
if i[0] == 0 or row[0] < i[0]:
   message = await ctx.send(embed=emb,components=[disnake.ui.Button(label='Remove the warning', style=ButtonStyle.secondary)])
   try:
       responce = await client.wait_for('button_click', check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author,timeout=60)
   except asyncio.TimeoutError:
       await ctx.edit_original_message(components=[])
       return
   if responce.component.label == 'Remove the warning':
       await unwarnslash.unwarn_slash(ctx, member)
       await ctx.edit_original_message(components=[])
       await responce.response.defer()
elif row[0] >= i[0]:
   await ctx.send(embed=emb)
   await kickslash.kick_slash(ctx, member, 'Exceeded the number of warnings')
```